# Help in this teminology in Hartshorne's algebraic geometry book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology

I'm studying [Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry book](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Algebraic_Geometry.html?id=3rtX9t-nnvwC&redir_esc=y) and on page 51:

[image]

What the author means by $M_{\mathfrak p}$ and "length"? I suppose $S_{\mathfrak p}$ is the localization of the ring $S$ at $\mathfrak p$, right?

Length means dimension in this context?

Thanks

Comment: This www.math.hawaii.edu/~lee/algebra/jordan.pdf motivates the notion of length for modules by first looking at dimension in vector spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M_\mathfrak{p}$ denotes the localization of the $S$-module $M$ at the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset S$. It's defined exactly how you'd expect:
$$M_\mathfrak{p}=\{\tfrac{m}{s}:m\in M, s\notin \mathfrak{p}\}$$
For any $\mathfrak{p}$, we have that $M_\mathfrak{p}$ is a module over $S_\mathfrak{p}$. [Here is the relevant Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_module).

Then there is a notion of the *length of a module* $N$: it is the length of the largest chain of strict submodules
$$0\subsetneq N_0\subsetneq N_1\subsetneq\cdots N_n\subsetneq N$$
[Here is the relevant Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_of_a_module).

Thus, Hartshorne is defining $\mu_\mathfrak{p}(M)$ to be the length of $M_\mathfrak{p}$ as an $S_\mathfrak{p}$-module.

Comment: The second sentence is technically correct but a bit misleading, as it doesn't explain when two elements $m/s$, $m'/s'$ are equal to one another.